# Is there a setting in Excel that prevents pictures from being added to the workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that inserts pictures into a workbook.
The purpose of the pictures is to add signatures to the workbook via an add-in I have built.

This code for pics sometimes doesn't work though.

Each user has the pictures saved on their computer in the same place.
This is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
imagePath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\Ticks\B1.png"
imgLeft = ActiveCell.Left
imgTop = ActiveCell.Top
ws.Shapes.AddPicture _
Filename:=imagePath, _
LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, _
Left:=imgLeft, _
Top:=imgTop, _
Width:=12.15, _
Height:=12.15
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
```

I occasionally get the *unable to get the insert property of the picture class* error, and I don't know why.
The pictures are there and the names are all correct.

It only gives the error on certain documents - which is why I think there is a setting that can be changed.
The rest of the time this works perfectly, and the 7 people who use it regularly, very rarely report an issue. 
I thought it was only on old XLS files (this was where it broke down most frequently), but it happens on XLSX files too.

Comment: Could the `ActiveCell` be on the last row of the sheet?  Your last line says `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select` which would try and select a cell off the bottom of the sheet & throw an error.  Is the sheet protected?  That might stop the code from inserting a picture.

Comment: Side note - rather than using "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns\` have you tried `Application.UserLibraryPath`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it breaks down before the offset kicks in. It's usually used in the first 50 rows of each worksheet - so never on massive files.
all files are unprotected too, I have checked that.

Comment: You could replace the whole `imagepath` line with `imagepath = application.UserLibraryPath & "Ticks\B1.png"` - will always point to the correct location.

Comment: I tried changing it as you suggested, same error

Comment: I found the setting - file, options, Advanced, display options for this workbook - all must be ticked.

Comment: You should also be checking to confirm that the file exists prior to trying to add it.